# HTML to PDF A4 printable size

Tags: html, pdf, printing, page-size

I need to design brochure in HTML from which a pdf will be generated. How can I make it to be A4 size and printable after transform to pdf? The HTML will consist of images and text and needs to look the same as HTML version. Is it possible? Should I use 300dpi pixel size -> 2480 X 3508 pixels?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a css file that synchonises the layout and even has print-specific directives.  You can specify sizes in terms of physical dimensions, although this will be subject to interpretation on the screen.

An article on doing for-print CSS can be seen [here.](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/)